# Percentage formlae for each Vehicle parked?

Tags: percentages

I'm writing a C++ Car park program that holds Cars, Vans and Bikes, and I need to be able to give the **percentage** for each item that is currently in the car park.

To make my question short, if the car park has 5 cars, 4 vans and 2 bikes, **what is the formulae for working out the percentage of cars, vans and bikes currently park** so I can implement it to my program?

Comment: If currenlty park $4$ cars then the percentage of currently parking cars is $\frac{4}{5}=0.8=80\%$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the percentages by dividing the total number of one type of vehicle by the total number of vehicles in the garage.

$$
P_{car}=\frac{\text{number of cars}}{\text{total number vehicles}}=\frac{5}{11}=0.\overline{45}=45.\overline{45}\%
$$
$$
P_{van}=\frac{\text{number of vans}}{\text{total number vehicles}}=\frac{4}{11}=0.\overline{36}=36.\overline{36}\%
$$
$$
P_{bike}=\frac{\text{number of bikes}}{\text{total number vehicles}}=\frac{2}{11}=0.\overline{18}=18.\overline{18}\%
$$